# htaccess slash_based

Tags: php, .htaccess, mvc

mvc работает на slash based urls  => muweb.com/controller/param1/param2

как переписать `muweb.com/controller/?item=45` на `muweb.com/controller/45` или даже на `muweb.com/controller/item45`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как и в большинстве вопросов такого типа, непонятно что на что Вы хотите менять. Т.е., неясно, что должен вводить пользователь в адресной строке и что должно быть после перенаправления. Поэтому рассмотрим оба варианта перенаправления с помощью файла `.htaccess`.

---

**Вариант 1.1.**

Исходный адрес - `muweb.com/controller/?item=45`, адрес после перенаправления - `muweb.com/controller/45`.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} item=(\d+)
RewriteRule ^(controller)$ $1/%1? [L,R]
```

---

**Вариант 1.2.**

Исходный адрес - `muweb.com/controller/?item=45`, адрес после перенаправления - `muweb.com/controller/item45`.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} item=(\d+)
RewriteRule ^(controller)$ $1/item%1? [L,R]
```

---

**Вариант 2.1.**

Исходный адрес - `muweb.com/controller/45`, адрес после перенаправления - `muweb.com/controller/?item=45`.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^(controller)/(\d+)/?$ $1?item=$2 [L,R,QSA]
```

---

**Вариант 2.2.**

Исходный адрес - `muweb.com/controller/item45`, адрес после перенаправления - `muweb.com/controller/?item=45`.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^(controller)/(item)(\d+)/?$ $1?$2=$3 [L,R,QSA]
```

---

**Вариант 2.3.**

Исходный адрес - `muweb.com/controller/item45`, ***либо*** `muweb.com/controller/45`, адрес после перенаправления - `muweb.com/controller/?item=45`.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^(controller)/(\d+)/?$ $1?item=$2 [L,R,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(controller)/(item)(\d+)/?$ $1?$2=$3 [L,R,QSA]
```

Comment: Спасибо, за такой развернутый ответ, суть моего вопросы состояла в в то чтобы после submit из формы поиска параметры GET сразу передавались в контроллер через слеш, я вот только одного не могу понять Htaccess после сабмита сразу конвертирует  URL  в слешовый формат и он передается в контроллер или просто после перехода сам URL выглядит через слеш  а параметры в контроллере доступны только через GET

Comment: @ConeEnoc Тут я помочь не могу. Лучше задайте отдельный вопрос.